# Nonlinear square optimization task in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

let us suppose that we have following  task:Find the optimal value of weights

[image]

so that  minimize following equation

[image]

where var-means variance of given x1 variable,  also we have constraint that sum of these weights should be equal to 1
[image]

i have initialized  anonymous function and weights for initial points

```
w=[0.5; 0.5];


  >> f=@(x1,x2) (w(1)*w(1)*var(x1)+w(2)*w(2)*var(x2))

f = 

    @(x1,x2)(w(1)*w(1)*var(x1)+w(2)*w(2)*var(x2))
```

i think i should use function fmincon,
i have created A matrix

```
A=[1;1];
```

and b  column

```
b=[1];
```

then i tried following fun

```
weighs=fmincon(f(x1,x2),w,A,b)
```

but it gives me error

```
Error using optimfcnchk (line 287)
FUN must be a function, a valid string expression, or an inline function
object.
```

could you help me please what is wrong? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the function in `fmincon` as a function handle or anonymous function; `f(x1,x2)` evaluates to a scalar double, not a function handle. `fmincon` will want to evaluate this function with current values of `w` to check for the quality of the solution, so it needs a way to feed `w` as an input.

Thus, you need to

- Change the function definition to `f(w,x1,x2)`, i.e. 
  `f=@(w,x1,x2) (w(1)*w(1)*var(x1)+w(2)*w(2)*var(x2))`
- Write the `fmincon` call as `fmincon(@(u)f(u,x1,x2),...)`

However, I would suggest to substitute `1-w(2)` for `w(1)` (or vice versa) in your problem to reformulate it as an unconstrained optimization of one variable (unless `w` is a real weight, and has to remain between 0 and 1, in which case you still need a constraint).

Comment: so how my function will have a final form?

Comment: As w are weights, we probably need to add the bounds 0 <= w(i) <= 1. So no longer an unconstrained problem.

Comment: weights can be negative as well,please could you post complete solution with answer?